# OpenVPN: doesn't route between subnets

Tags: routing, openvpn

I already started to pull my hair out.

Trying to get the Server and Client talk to each other using their private subnet addresses (not OpenVPN addresses).

Server IP: 10.0.0.111/24, Client Net: 10.20.30.120/24

Connection is possible between `10.8.0.1 (server) <=> 10.8.0.10 (client)`.

But no connection is possible between `10.0.0.111 (server) <=> 10.20.30.120 (client)`.

Using latest OpenVPN distribution. Both machines are Windows 7 32-bit. No error messages in the log files. Firewall is turned off on both ends.

Please help.

server.ovpn:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
dev-node MyTap
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh1024.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0"
client-config-dir ccd
route 10.20.30.0 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.10
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

ccd/client1

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.10 255.255.255.0
iroute 10.20.30.0 255.255.255.0
```

client.ovpn

```
client
dev tun
dev-node MyTap
proto udp
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 3
```

Server's routing table:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1       10.0.0.111     10
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.0.0.111    266
       10.0.0.111  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.0.0.111    266
       10.0.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.0.0.111    266
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.8.0.1    276
         10.8.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.1    276
       10.8.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.1    276
       10.20.30.0    255.255.255.0        10.8.0.10         10.8.0.1     20
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.0.0.111    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.8.0.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.0.0.111    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.1    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Client's routing table:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.20.30.1     10.20.30.120     10
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         10.8.0.1        10.8.0.10    276
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         10.8.0.10    276
        10.8.0.10  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.8.0.10    276
       10.8.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.8.0.10    276
       10.20.30.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      10.20.30.120    266
     10.20.30.120  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.20.30.120    266
     10.20.30.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.20.30.120    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.20.30.120    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.8.0.10    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.20.30.120    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.8.0.10    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: It looks like to me route issue at first glance. Your hop is not there to route the traffic. Can you double check the route again and add correct route for subnet 10.0.0.0/24 which belongs to server group from VPN server. You can also check from VPN IP are you able to ping those servers or not?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out after a long battle. I was under the impression that OpenVPN acts like a router between the interfaces, but it does NOT!

How can I setup a win 7 PC as a router?
https://superuser.com/questions/394505/how-can-i-setup-a-win-7-pc-as-a-router

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters

Value Name: IpEnableRouter
Value Type: REG_DWORD
Value Data: 1
```